# SharePoint 2010 installation and permission

Tags: 2010

I had tried to installed SharePoint 2010 on a window 2008 R2 server both as a standalone and server farm(complete). In both case, when I go to Central Aministration page, the ribbon is completely disabled. Anyone know what is the problem?

The account i used to install SharePoint is my domain account, which belong to the local admin group of the server. And the server have SQL 2008 R2 installed

I tried to follow these instruction page and still didn't solve my problem (i don't even know what is the problem in the first place. Any help is much appreciate)

http://mosshowto.blogspot.com/2009/11/installing-sharepoint-2010-windows-2008.html
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262243.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869(office.14).aspx

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're using UAC then you need to Start IE as an Administrator when you go to central admin - right click, start as Administrator.

http://sensoft2000-sharepoint.blogspot.com/2010/06/new-ribbon-icon-disabled-in-central.html